# get no devuelve nada tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

estoy empezando con tkinter y quiero obtener el texto de ENTRY

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("exolar")
root.iconbitmap("lapiz.ico")
root.geometry("500x500")


t1 = Entry(root,cursor="plus")
t1.grid(column=0, row=2)
def save():
    print(t1.get())
save = Button(root,text="save!",command=save)
save.grid(column=3,row=8)
root.mainloop()
```

pero no devuelve nada
devuelve un espacio vacio

mi version de python:3.8.5

Comment: Funciona perfectamente (hay que escribir algo en el campo de entrada, claro!)

Comment: De todas formas, aunque me funciona, no me parece buena idea llamar igual a la función (`save`) que al botón (`save`). La segunda asignación (el botón) redefine el simbolo `save`, que ya no se referirá a la función (aunque eso no afecta al funcionamiento porque cuando el comando `save` se asignó al parámetro `command` del botóin, `save`  aún se refería a la función)

Comment: ami no me funciona por eso pregunto

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estás llamando al botón igual que el comando que este ejecuta, entonces lo único que hace es que se llame a sí mismo y salga ese espacio vacío o `None`. Simplemente debes llamar al botón `save` de otra manera, algo así como `save_button`.

Lo otro es que debes escribir algo en el campo de texto por que sino te dará una entrada vacía.

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/late-answers/364121)

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que estas nombrando una variable y una función del mismo modo,te recomiendo cambiar el nombre del botón por `boton_save`, esto quedaria algo asi:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title("exolar")
root.iconbitmap("lapiz.ico")
root.geometry("500x500")


t1 = Entry(root,cursor="plus")
t1.grid(column=0, row=2)
def save():
    print(t1.get())
boton_save = Button(root,text="save!",command=save)
boton_save.grid(column=3,row=8)
root.mainloop()
```

también te recomiendo no importar todo el modulo directamente sino importarlo de esta forma `import tkinter as tk`, para poder usarlo de esta forma tendrás que escribirlo así `tk.(funcion)`, tu código final quedaría algo así:

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("exolar")
root.iconbitmap("lapiz.ico")
root.geometry("500x500")


t1 = tk.Entry(root,cursor="plus")
t1.grid(column=0, row=2)
def save():
    print(t1.get())

boton_save = tk.Button(root,text="save!",command=save)
boton_save.grid(column=3,row=8)
root.mainloop()
```